# snappy filesystem layout?

Tags: snap, fhs

Is there a way for an ubuntu snap to provide files in the FHS filesystem hierarchy, e.g. binaries in /usr/bin, package data in /usr/share/, configuration files in /etc ?
If not, what is the best practice to use such resources provided by a snap?
Shall one use /snap// instead of  every time?

Answer (score 1):

No, a snap is self-contained. It may of course contain a bin/, usr/bin/, etc. within itself, but it cannot place things into the system's /bin/, /usr/bin/, etc.

The best practice to utilize such resources provided by the snap is to export them from the snap using the "apps" keyword in the YAML. For example, say I have an executable shell script called `hello.sh`, which contains the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "hello snap guru"
```

And I have a `snapcraft.yaml` that looks like this:

```
name: hello
version: 1
summary: my summary
description: my description

apps:
  run:
    command: hello.sh

parts:
  hello:
    plugin: copy
    files:
      hello.sh: bin/
```

After you run `snapcraft` on this and install the resulting snap, you'll notice that hello.sh is contained within the snap's bin/ directory, which is of course not in your PATH so you can't directly call it. However, when the snap is installed, snappy creates a new script inside /snap/bin/ for each item in the "apps" keyword (`run` in this case), and /snap/bin/ is in your PATH. You should be able to run the hello.sh script just by using `<snap name>.<app name>`:

```
$ hello.run
hello snap guru
```

Comment: Nice, and what about things not script? Like something I normally put to /usr/share/<packagename>/?
Is there a reference documentation fro snapcraft.yaml?

Comment: There's no real convention for that. Read-only architecture independent data (i.e. the data that would typically be placed in `/usr/share/`) can be anywhere in the snap, and the application should use it from there. So you can make a `usr/share/` directory within the snap and refer to it from the app using `$SNAP/usr/share/`, but those conventions make less sense when everything is self-contained. You could also do simply `$SNAP/data`.

Comment: My question is how to use that data from something using the package?